# Validator for `bool` field fails with: value could not be parsed to a boolean

Tags: python, validation, python-typing, pydantic

I am using Pydantic for a data model and validation:

```py
class Seller(BaseModel):
    seller_id: int
    display_name: str
    fulfilled_by_vender: bool
```

The `Seller` model is used as a nested field in some models. JSON or `dict` is being passed, where the data-type for `fulfilled_by_vender` is sometimes a string.

Is there any config that will enable parsing `fulfilled_by_vender` to check if it is a string?

I have tried using a validator, but it results in an error.

```py
class Seller(BaseModel):
    seller_id: int
    display_name: str
    fulfilled_by_vender: bool

    @validator("fulfilled_by_vender")
    def verify_if_exists(cls, value):
        return 'Packed & shipped by Vender' in value
```

> value could not be parsed to a boolean (type=type_error.bool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pre` flag, which will cause the validator to be called prior to other validation:

```py
class Seller(BaseModel):
    seller_id: int
    display_name: str
    fulfilled_by_vender: bool

    @validator("fulfilled_by_vender", pre=True)
    def verify_if_exists(cls, value):
        return 'Packed & shipped by Vender' in value
```

Comment: Thank you so much @christoher for the response, can I re-use this validator function in some other model as well ? Will I required to create a custom type to handle this ?

Comment: @Saqib If you have numerous fields that need the same validation pattern, you can inherit from a custom base model.